# How to retrieve multiple collections using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

So I'm trying to retrieve multiple docs using Mongoose and render them using the HBS view engine. Unfortunatley, the only way I know how to render the view is to call `res.render()` inside the callback to the `find()` function used to retrieve documents from the MongoDB database. As such I can only retrieve one doc at a time and I'd like to know how to save multiple docs to variables and then render using `res.render()`. Anybody know how to do this? Router code below.

Basically, I'm pulling from multiple collections and want to know how to save the output of the `find()` function as variables and then pass them to the `res.render()` function to render it. You can see my hammed attempt below to save the results as variables which only returns a promise.

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var moment = require('moment');

var supportForumListSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  numPosts: Number,
  dateCreated: Date
}, {collection: 'support-forum-listing'});

var artworkForumListSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  numPosts: Number,
  dateCreated: Date
}, {collection: 'artwork-forum-listing'});

var supportForumList = mongoose.model('supportForumList', supportForumListSchema);
var artworkForumList = mongoose.model('artworkForumList', artworkForumListSchema);

tempDate = new Date(1542325638042);
currentDate = new Date(1542333003752);
console.log("current date:" + currentDate.toDateString());
tempHoursAgo = currentDate - tempDate;
tempHoursAgo = tempHoursAgo / (1000*60*60);
tempDateString = tempHoursAgo.toFixed(0);   // could use Number(string) to convert back to number
console.log(tempDateString + "hours ago");

// temp new posts array
var newPosts = [
    {postTitle: "Need help!", numViews: 1, datePosted: tempDateString},
    {postTitle: "Unknown identifier", numViews: 0, datePosted: tempDateString},
    {postTitle: "Messing up my normals", numViews: 3, datePosted: tempDateString},
    {postTitle: "Anyone able to help?", numViews: 3, datePosted: tempDateString}
];

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    artworkDoc = artworkForumList.find().then(function(doc){
        return doc;
    });
    console.log(artworkDoc);
    supportForumList.find().then(function(supportDoc){
        res.render('index', { title: 'Home - 3D Artists Forum', headerTitle: "3D Artist Forums", supportForumList: supportDoc , artworkForumList: artworkDoc, latestPosts: newPosts});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that requests are async calls, so you should chain then in order to get the desired result, otherwise "  supportForumList.find()" might respond before artworkForumList.find()

Try this way

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    artworkDoc = artworkForumList.find().then(function(doc){
      return doc;
    }).then( doc => {
    
      supportForumList.find().then(function(supportDoc){
      res.render('index', { title: 'Home - 3D Artists Forum', headerTitle: "3D Artist Forums", supportForumList: supportDoc , artworkForumList: doc, latestPosts: newPosts});
    });;
      

});
```

In this approach, supportForumList.find() is executed only when artworkForumList.find() has responded and you have data in the "doc" variable, and then that data is passed as a parameter.

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Or same code with arrow function:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    artworkForumList.find()
        .then(doc =>
            supportForumList.find()
                .then(supportDoc => res.render(title: 'Home - 3D Artists Forum', headerTitle: "3D Artist Forums", , { supportForumList: supportDoc, artworkForumList: doc, latestPosts: newPosts })))
}
```